# nodejs' buffer received from C is divided into two parts

Tags: c, node.js, tcp

I am using tcp to transfer data. The server code is written by C, and client code is written by nodejs. 
When I send one buffer, sometimes the client will receive two parts of this buffer, the console.log function will trigger twice, but sometimes it works well.
following are nodejs code and C code.
nodejs code:

```js
var client = new net.Socket();
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data:', data)
});
```

C code:

```
send(socket_file, buffer, strlen(buffer),0)
```

Comment: That's how streams work in Node: they may trigger multiple `data` events (+ various others). You may have to do some internal housekeeping if you need to assemble the entire message that the server sent.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical for TCP, which is a stream-oriented (as opposed to packet-oriented like UDP) protocol after all.

There's no guarantee that one write to the network equals one read at the other end, multiple writes may be delivered together and single writes may be split.

You must add an applicaton-level message protocol.